# Does C support function expressions?

Tags: c, syntax, functional-programming

Is it possible to use function expressions in C? For example, I have the following code snippet (inside the `main` function):

```
void print_line(char *data) {
  printf("%s\n", data);
}

// print all elements in my_list
list_foreach(&my_list, print_line);
```

I'd like to do something like this instead:

```
list_foreach(&my_list, void (char *data) {
  printf("%s\n", data);
});
```

Is anything like that possible in C?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but that's why I love C++, it gives you this and more for cheaper price than C!

Comment: @AraK: For cheaper price than C? What does "cheaper" mean here? The C++ way is probably slower, no?

Comment: Cheaper here means that the compiler is able to collapse the abstraction to get the maximum performance. Compare for example the use of a functor(or lambda), with the use of function pointers. Introducing aliasing doesn't help much in producing the best out of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a word, No.  At least not in a Javascript-like syntax.  Function pointers are as close as your are going to get.  There is very little difference between the two syntactically.  If you are looking for the behavior of closures or inner functions, then you definitely are not going to see them soon.

Comment: GNU C supports [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), but they aren't in standard C.

Answer (score 4):

Not in standard C, no. Apple has introduced a feature called blocks that will let you do this and it's been submitted for standardization, but it's not there yet (if it will ever make it through). Apple's syntax looks like this:

```
list_foreach(my_list, ^(char *data) {
    printf("%s\n", data);
});
```

It's basically function pointer syntax with `*` replaced with `^` (and inference for the return type in expressions).

Comment: Oh, that sounds interesting. Well, as long as I can't use it in gcc, I probably won't use it. :(

Comment: Where can I found it? it's a gcc C extension for apple's architecture or another compiler?

Comment: @Jack: It's in Apple's now-unsupported fork of GCC and it's also in Clang (http://clang.llvm.org), which has Apple as its main corporate sponsor. (If you use Clang, I think you'll want to pass the -fblocks flag to enable the language extension.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in plain C. However you can fake this with macro:

```
#define FOR_EACH(type, x, array, size, code) \
                 do { \
                      int i; \
                      for (i=0; i<size; ++i) { \
                        type x = array[i]; \
                        code \
                      } \
                 } while(0)

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
  FOR_EACH(int, x, arr, 7, printf("%d ", 1 << x); );

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** 

I've re-coded example to be more portable - without using GCC blocks extension.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not anything like Objective-C blocks, closures, etc. But what about using **function pointers** instead?